# How to call a method without knowing it's name in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, call

Is it possible to call a method without knowing it's name? I imagine it being a method stored as a variable like so:

```
public static Method Example;

private static void DoSomething()
{
    //Something
}

private static void Main()
{
    Example = DoSomething();
}

public static void ExecuteSomething()
{
    Example();
}
```

Is there something like this, or of similar function? I've looked at delegates and I'm not sure if I understand them correctly, or if it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Delegates are exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Change `public static method Example` to `public static Action Example`, but you'd still need its name to refer to it when assinging

Comment: Also, the assignment would look like `Example = DoSomething;` (without the `()`)

Comment: "hey you method, come here, no, no not you, you there with a big signature" (sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is called a `delegate`. They can be used in variable/field/property/eventhandler declarations. C# comes with some handy generics that you can use to describe the function you expect. Some examples:

```
Action                      // A void function
Action<T>                   // A void function that accepts a parameter of type T
Action<Tin1, Tin2, ...>     // A void function that accepts Tx parameters

Func<T>                     // A function that returns an object of type T
Func<Tout, Tin1, Tin2, ...> // A function that returns Tout an accepts Tx as parameters

Predicate<T>                // A function that returns bool and accepts parameter T
```

Or if you want to write your own delegates with the `delegate` keyword:

```
delegate void MySpecialEventHandler(object sender, object data)
```

Example:

```
//EventHandler definition
public delegate void PrintedSomethingEventHandler(string message);

//Event
public event PrintedSomethingEventHandler PrintedSomething;

//e.g. "Function Hook"
private Func<string,string> _externalFilter;

public void SetFilter(Func<string,string> filter)
{
    _externalFilter = filter;
}

private void PrintA(string message)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(message);
}

private void PrintB(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}

private bool ContainsProfanity(string message)
{
    return message.Contains("%$&!");
}

public void Print(string message, bool debug)
{
    Action<string> action;
    Predicate<string> filter = ContainsProfanity;

    if(filter(message))
        return;

    if(_externalFilter != null)
        message = _externalFilter(message);

    if(debug)
        action = PrintA;
    else
        action = PrintB;

    action(message);

    if(PrintedSomethingEventHandler != null)
        PrintedSomethingEventHandler(message);
}
```

Comment: Also, [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) to MSDN for more info

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it working! I guess I should've researched delegates further.